# Elasticsearch - behavior of regexp query against a non-analyzed field

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

What is the default behavior for a regexp query against a non-analyzed field? Also, is that the same answer when dealing with .raw fields?

After everything i've read, i understand the following.
1. RegExp queries will work on analyzed and non-analyzed fields.
2. A regexp query should work across the entire phrase rather than just matching on a single token in non-analyzed fields.
Here's the problem though. I can not actually get this to work. I've tried it across multiple fields.

The setup i'm working with is a stock elk install and i'm dumping pfsense and snort logs into it with a basic parser. I'm currently on Kibana 4.3 and ES 2.1

I did a query to look at the mapping for one of the fields and it indicates it is not_analyzed, yet the regex does not work across the entire field.

```
"description": {
  "type": "string",
  "norms": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
}
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

- if a field is non-analyzed, the field is only a single token.
- It's same answer when dealing with .raw fields, at least in my work.
- You can use groovy script:

  matcher = (doc[fields.raw].value =~ /${pattern}/ );
  if(matcher.matches()) {
      matcher.group(matchname)}

you can pass pattern and matchname in params.

What's meaning of `tried it across multiple fields.`? If your situation is more complex, maybe you could make a native java plugin.

**UPDATE**

```
{
  "script_fields" : {
    "regexp_field" : {
      "script" : "matcher = (doc[fieldname].value =~ /${pattern}/ );if(matcher.matches()) {matcher.group(matchname)}",
      "params" : {
        "pattern" : "your pattern",
        "matchname" : "your match",
        "fieldname" : "fields.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using code, like groovy, for your regular expression matching, then you're using that particular library's rules rather than the lucene syntax. So to clarify, i'm trying to write a regex query that will match one field in its entirety. i.e. the whole phrase instead of just a single word within that phrase.  What i meant by trying it across multiple fields is that it's not just one field i'm  having trouble with. It's all of them.

Comment: you can use this code in elasticsearch syntax: see my update

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looking at the documentation, it looks like you have to enable scripting for this to work. 
Are there any other suggestions to allow this to work without enabling scripting?

Comment: If you don't want to use groovy script, you can wirte a native java plugin. Although the plugin can be think as another scripting.[help for plugin authors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/plugin-authors.html) I do not know third way now.